# Convert a start and end ip range to a net mask

Tags: php, ip, subnet

Good morning,

I am trying to get the subnet mask from a start and end ip in PHP.

```
Eg;
14.1.32.0 and 14.1.64.0 is 255.255.224.0
```

But there doesn't seem to be any built in function for this?
Everything I have searched refers to CDIR and trying to get all the ips etc so it seems I am trying to go the other way.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 255 - (64 - 32 + 1)?  Also you are assuming your broadcast address will always be 255, which could not be always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

```
$ip = "14.1.32.0"; 
$ip2 = "14.1.64.0";
echo long2ip(ip2long($ip) - ip2long($ip2));
```